# How can I use the dart when I installed the Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I installed the Flutter SDK in my Mac:

```
dele-MacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ flutter --version
  ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
  ║ A new version of Flutter is available!                                     ║
  ║                                                                            ║
  ║ To update to the latest version, run "flutter upgrade".                    ║
  ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝


Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 • channel stable •
https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 27321ebbad (9 weeks ago) • 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
Engine • revision 2994f7e1e6
Tools • Dart 2.7.0
dele-MacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ dart --version
-bash: dart: command not found
```

you see `Tools • Dart 2.7.0`, I want to know how to use `dart`? there is no available PATH for dart.

Answer (score 1):

The location of dart is in /flutter_install_location/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin (at least for windows)

You could alternatively install dart sdk from:
https://dart.dev/get-dart